# Run node.js from upstart (ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, node.js, upstart

I'm trying to setup upstart script to start/stop my node.js application.

Here is my upstart script:

```
#!upstart

description "node.js server"
author "marduk"

start on filesystem
stop on runlevel [!2345]
oom never
expect daemon
respawn
respawn limit 10 60

script
        export HOME="/home/domains/srg-internal-dev"

        echo $$ > /var/run/node-srg-internal-dev.pid
        exec sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/node /home/domains/srg-internal-dev/api/server.js >> /home/domains/srg-internal-dev/node.log
2>&1
end script

pre-start script
        echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Starting" >> /home/domains/srg-internal-dev/node.log
end script

pre-stop script
        rm /var/run/node-srg-internal-dev.pid
        echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Stopping" >> /home/domains/srg-internal-dev/node.log
end script
```

I checked this script file:

> $ init-checkconf /etc/init.d/nodesrg.conf
>
> File /etc/init.d/nodesrg.conf: syntax ok

But when I try to start node I get:

```
$ start nodesrg
start: Unknown job: nodesrg
```

What I'm doing wrong? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving nodesrg.conf to `/etc/init`, not /etc/init.d. Init.d is where the SYSV-style scripts go, upstart configuration belongs in the former.

Use `initctl list` to verify that it is showing up as an upstart service after you have moved the file.

If it doesn't, you can use `initctl reload-configuration` and try again.